# My simple C++ program calculates total payroll amount and I want to know a better and more efficient way to do this

Tags: c++

I tried to implement the do..while loop in a simple program. In the program, I ask for a payroll amount, then calculate the sum of the payroll and outputs the sum and the number of valid entries. That's too simple so I decided to add some error checking.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

const int SENTINEL = -1;

int main(){

int payroll, payroll_sum, counter = 0;


do{

    cout << "Enter a payroll amount (-1 to end): ";
    cin >> payroll;

    if((payroll < SENTINEL)){
        cout << "\nError!\nPlease enter a correct value.\n" << endl;
        int main(payroll);
    }
    else{
        payroll_sum += payroll;
        counter += 1;
        cout << "\n";
    }

    if(payroll == SENTINEL){
        payroll_sum += 1;
        counter -= 1;
    }

}while(payroll != SENTINEL);


cout << "\n\nTotal payroll amount is: " << payroll_sum;

cout << "\nTotal number of entries is: " << counter;


return 0;

}
```

The code works, but it bugs me that I have to deduct one from the counter and add one to the sum because I don't know how to make the program ignore the SENTINEL input. And, I'm sure that there's a better way to do the error handling. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `int main(payroll);` supposed to do? Does this code really compile?

Comment: @EJP My mistake. I wanted to return the payroll so far back to main when repeating main because if I called main then the amount of sum would disappear right? And even if that were to work I should've put `payroll_sum` instead. This wouldn't work though, would it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would have written it as it's quite a bit cleaner. A few things I noticed that you may want to take note of:

1. It's good practice to initiate variables when you declare them.
2. Read up about `continue` and `break` in loops as well as when to use a `do-while` or a `while` loop.

Happy coding!

```
const int SENTINEL = -1;
int main() {
int payroll_sum = 0;
int payroll = 0;
int counter = 0;

    while (payroll != SENTINEL) {
        cout << "Enter a payroll amount (-1 to end): ";
        cin >> payroll;
        if(payroll == SENTINEL) break;

        if((payroll < SENTINEL)){
            cout << "\nError!\nPlease enter a correct value.\n" << endl;
            continue;
        }
        else {
            payroll_sum += payroll;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\nTotal payroll amount is: " << payroll_sum;
    cout << "\nTotal number of entries is: " << counter;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll read up on continue and break and check up on when to use while and do...while. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
continue;
```

Instead of

```
int main(payroll);
```

And also, initialize `payroll_sum` by using

```
payroll_sum=0
```

Before the loop. Also, remove

```
if(payroll == SENTINEL){
     payroll_sum += 1;
     counter -= 1;
 }
```

And change the last two `cout`s to

```
cout << "\n\nTotal payroll amount is: " << payroll_sum+1;
cout << "\nTotal number of entries is: " << counter-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple question about condition logic. There are plenty of different ways to structure your if conditions but one way that would be more efficient than your current code could be:

```
while(true)
{
  cout << "Enter a payroll amount (-1 to end): ";
  cin >> payroll;

 if(payroll == SENTINEL)
   break;

 if((payroll < SENTINEL))
 {
     cout << "\nError!\nPlease enter a correct value.\n" << endl;
     int main(payroll);
 }
 else
 {
     payroll_sum += payroll;
     counter += 1;
     cout << "\n";
 } 
}
```

If you don't like using while(true) I can provide another example. Cheers